# NodeJS Check Request/Response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using sockets, how can you detect if `req` and or `res` is not undefined, and if undefined, redirect the client?

Here's my authenticate function

```
function authenticate(req,res,next) {
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        fs.readFile('./html/login.html', "utf8", function(err, html) {
            res.send(html);
        });
    } else next();
}
```

Which works perfectly with `app.get` or `app.post`. However, it doesn't seem to work for a socket route.

```
app.io.route('move', authenticate, function(req) { //does not work, 'next() is undefined'

app.get("/",authenticate, function(req, res) { //works perfectly
```

How can I authenticate that a client has a session via websockets, and provide a response to avoid triggering an error?

(This situation is caused by: 1. Client logs in. 2. I make a server restart. 3. Clients are NOT logged out, and try to move, but the no longer have a session and it triggers an error)

Comment: the docs don't indicate the ability to pass three arguments to app.io.route https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples